# CSS Can't correctly dock Right Sided Panel

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm new to ASP and CSS so this question, I don't doubt, is going to seem very basic to many.

I am trying to create a web page with a panel on the left side, a panel on the right side, and the main content inbetween.

My markup looks as follows -

```
 <body>
    <div id="Header">
        <a id="A1" runat="server"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="LeftPanel">
        This is my LeftPanel</div>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MainContent">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpMainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="RightPanel">
        This is my RightPanel</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I have a separate CSS file to provide the layout details, which reads -

```
#LeftPanel
{
    margin-left: 100px;  
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(0, 165, 240);
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}

#MainContent
{
    color: Black;
    margin-left: 120px;  
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}

#RightPanel
{    
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(0, 165, 240);
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Now my LeftPanel appears on the left side of the screen as desired, and my MainContent appears to the right of the LeftPanel (again as planned).  However, for reasons I can't work out my RightPanel appears on the left side of the screen and below the LeftPanel and MainContent divisions.

I'm pretty sure it'll be something simple, but like I said, I'm very new to ASP and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
float: left;
```

to #MainContent and #RightPanel

I'm also wondering, if this is a bit too much: width: 1000px;

Comment: I'd previously tried the float: left in both #MainContent and #RightPanel and that didn't help.  But when I added them in again AND tried your suggestion of reducing the #MainContent width it worked!!  Thank You.  However, if the user reduces the size of the window, the panels appears under each other again.  How can I fix the panels so they stay in place when the User reduces the window size?

Comment: You would need an outer div like this (you will have to adjust correct width, 1200 just an example):
        <div style="width:1200px">
            <div id="LeftPanel">This is my LeftPanel</div>                
            <div id="MainContent">Main content</div>
            <div id="RightPanel">This is my RightPanel</div>
        </div>